# Longest shortest path between any two nodes of a graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find two nodes that are furthest from each other in my Neo4j Database. For the purposes of my analysis, I am considering shortest distance between the two nodes as the distance between them. Therefore, the two nodes that are furthest will have longest shortest path between them. I am using the following syntax from Cypher to find the shortest node.

Given two nodes as shown in the Neo4j example documentation http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-shortest-path, I can run the following Cypher query.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((martin:Person)-[*..15]-(oliver:Person))
WHERE martin.name = 'Martin Sheen' AND oliver.name = 'Oliver Stone'
RETURN p
```

My database has over 1/2 million nodes. The brute force way will obviously take a long time. Is there any easy or faster way to get the two nodes?

[As an extra wrinkle .. the graph is weighted but this detail can be ignored.]

Comment: Are you looking for a single-source shortest path list, then trying to determine which of those is the longest?

Comment: Yes. My goal is to find two nodes, any nodes, that are far apart. To put in the context, I am still struggling to find cliques, as suggested by you in an earlier post. I am experimenting with partitioning the graph. To partition them effectively, I need two sufficiently far apart nodes to minimize chance that that they t belong to the same subgraph. PS - I have no formal education in graphs so I am trying to create some "make do" solution that are not perfect but get the work done. Appreciate you responding.

Comment: Hi @Anshul, just wanted to ask how you solved the problem?

Comment: I could not find a way to solve it efficiently. Below stated points by R2-D2 and Peter were the best leads. Do let us know if you find something more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want [all-pairs shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). This will give you a list with each node as a source and the shortest path to every other node. While it does do it by weight, you can simple use a weight of 1 for everything.

You'll have to implement this yourself in Java as Cypher doesn't have anything for this.

Comment: Yes, the best way to do this is probably to use a server extension to implement or reuse the Java API and Algos, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html